# BMI Calculator in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, model-view-controller

Hello I am very new to Kotlin and I am trying to build a BMI calculator using android Studio. I am trying to make it simple so by taking the user input it will then be calculated and return their BMI number followed by their status (Normal, Overweight, Obese).

There are 3 buttons that will be used:
Calculate- will calculate the users BMI depending on the results entered
Clear- Clear the screen for a new input to calculate
Heart Rate- Which will be an inactive button for now.

Currently when I press the calculate button the app shuts down immediately and does not return the BMI status nor BMI number. I need it to display "Your BMI is 'bmi#' you are 'obese, normal, or overweight'. But none of this happens and the app just crashes. Here is an example of my code

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val height = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.heightEditText)
        val weight = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.weightEditText)

        val calcButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
        val clearButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.clearButton)
        val bmiInfo = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.infoBMITextView)
        val heartRateButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.heartRateButton)


        // make heart rate button inactive
        heartRateButton.visibility = GONE

        // Make info text invisible until Calculate button is pressed
        bmiInfo.visibility = View.INVISIBLE

        calcButton.setOnClickListener{
            var heightValue = 0.0
            var weightValue = 0.0
            if(height.text.toString().isNotEmpty()){
                heightValue = height.text.toString().toDouble()
            }
            if(weight.text.toString().isNotEmpty()){
                weightValue = weight.text.toString().toDouble()
            }
            if(weightValue > 0.0 && heightValue > 0.0){
                val bmiValue = String.format("%0.2f", 
                weightValue*703/heightValue*heightValue)
                bmiInfo.text = "BMI is ${String.format("%0.2f",bmiValue)} you are 
                ${bmiResults(weightValue*703/heightValue*heightValue)}"
                bmiInfo.visibility = VISIBLE
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(
                    this, "Please input Weight and Height Values greater than 0",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }

        clearButton.setOnClickListener {
            weight.text.clear()
            height.text.clear()
        }

    }
```

And here is the function I made in order to perform the BMI calculation outside of the override fun

```
    fun bmiResults(bmi:Double):String{
        lateinit var answer: String
        if(bmi<18.5){
            answer="Underweight"
        } else if(bmi > 18.5 && bmi < 24.9) {
            answer="Normal"
        } else if(bmi > 24.9 && bmi < 30) {
            answer="Overweight"
        } else {
            answer="Obese"
        }
        return answer
    }
```

Here is my activity_main code in case that helps clear up my variable assignment and maybe that is causing an issue that I am not aware of.

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/weightTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="Weight"
        android:textColor="#3F51B5"
        android:textColorHighlight="#FAF6F6"
        android:textColorLink="#3F51B5"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/heightEditText" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/weightEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="in LBS"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:textColor="#3F51B5"
        android:textColorHighlight="#D6991E"
        android:textColorLink="#D6991E"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/weightTextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/heightTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="Height"
        android:textColor="#3F51B5"
        android:textColorHighlight="#FAF6F6"
        android:textColorLink="#3F51B5"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.492"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/heightEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="in inches"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:textColor="#3F51B5"
        android:textColorHighlight="#D6991E"
        android:textColorLink="#D6991E"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/heightTextView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="158dp"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:text="Calculate"
        android:textColorHighlight="#F6F0F0"
        android:textColorLink="#3F51B5"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/infoBMITextView"
        tools:ignore="UnknownId" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/infoBMITextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="INFO"
        android:textColor="#3F51B5"
        android:textColorHighlight="#FAF6F6"
        android:textColorLink="#3F51B5"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/weightEditText" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/clearButton"
        android:layout_width="146dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="341dp"
        android:text="Clear"
        android:textColorHighlight="#F6F0F0"
        android:textColorLink="#3F51B5"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/heartRateButton"
        android:layout_width="347dp"
        android:layout_height="67dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:text="Click for heart rate"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.515"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/clearButton" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

First time using stackoverflow so sorry if question is not the way it is suppose to be I tried providing all necessary information. thanks!

Comment: Hi @Dante, when an app crashes there is an error message generated on the [LogCat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat). Please edit your question and copy-past the output from Logcat which will point out the issue.

Comment: Hi @Tonnie I checked the logcat and was able to fix the issue thank you! With the help of Karunesh fixing that error it now works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in your code lies at the string-format conversion where you are not using the appropriate format to convert it ̣

While calculating bmiValue instead of :

```
val bmiValue = String.format("%0.2f", 
            weightValue*703/heightValue*heightValue)
```

Use the following format :

```
 val bmiValue = String.format(" %.2f",
                    weightValue*703/heightValue*heightValue)
```

Also while setting the bmiValue and the bmiResult to the textView , you need to do the same and also you have to convert the bmiValue from String to Double  to format again, which is not needed in my opinion , I have done the needed conversion assuming you might have a useCase for the same

So , Instead of setting the text in the following manner :

```
bmiInfo.text = "BMI is ${String.format("%0.2f",bmiValue)} you are + "${bmiResults(weightValue*703/heightValue*heightValue)}"
```

Do it in the following way :

```
  val bmiDouble = bmiValue.toDouble()
  bmiInfo.text = "BMI is ${String.format("%.2f",bmiDouble)} you are" +  
                     "${bmiResults(weightValue*703/heightValue*heightValue)}"
```

Comment: Wow thank you @Karunesh that little fix did it to the float as I checked the logcat and that is what is was saying was causing the issue.

Comment: do you have an idea how I can change this to a ViewModel to keep track of the UI data? Even if the device is rotated. I tried looking at the developer.android site for the documentation but have no clue how to implement this ViewModel

Comment: You need to have bmiValue , height and weight values inside ViewModel . Create a new Question for the same and comment its link here in the comment section .

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69239362/bmi-viewmodel-calculator-written-in-kotlin) is the new link for the question I had

Answer (score 0):

```
val bmi = weight.toFloat() / ((height.toFloat()/100)*(height.toFloat()/100))

val digit2format = String.format("%.2f", bmi).toFloat()
```

Comment: https://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-Your-Body-Mass-Index-(BMI)