# BMI ViewModel Calculator Written in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel, android-viewmodel

Hello I am trying to update my basic Kotlin code that calculates a users BMI based on their input. I have already went through the developer.android codelab practice and still can't get it.

For reference [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69139495/bmi-calculator-in-kotlin) is the link to the original code that has been fixed with the correct calculation so it is running.

But now I want to use a ViewModel so the UI data is saved on configuration changes. But so far this is all I have since I know the ViewModel needs to hold the data processing code and leaving the UI data in the regular class is fine since this will deal with the UI only.

I don't know how to bind all the data or properly access it from the ViewModel class. If someone can help. If my original code needs to be added in here for easier access I can add it, I just didn't want to clump this all together. Please someone help!

'''

```
class bmiViewModel : ViewModel() {


val height = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.heightEditText)
val weight = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.weightEditText)

calcButton.setOnClickListener{
    var heightValue = 0.0
    var weightValue = 0.0
    if(height.text.toString().isNotEmpty()){
        heightValue = height.text.toString().toDouble()
    }
    if(weight.text.toString().isNotEmpty()){
        weightValue = weight.text.toString().toDouble()
    }

    if(weightValue > 0.0 && heightValue > 0.0){
        val bmiValue = String.format(" %.2f",
            (weightValue*703)/(heightValue*heightValue))
        
        val bmiDouble = bmiValue.toDouble()
        bmiInfo.text = "BMI is ${String.format("%.2f",bmiDouble)} you are " +
                       "${bmiResults((weightValue*703)/(heightValue*heightValue))}"
        bmiInfo.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(
            this, "Please input Weight and Height Values greater than 0",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}

// function to decide users BMI status
private fun bmiResults(bmi:Double):String{
    lateinit var answer: String
    if(bmi<18.5){
        answer="Underweight"
    } else if(bmi > 18.5 && bmi < 24.9) {
        answer="Normal"
    } else if(bmi > 24.9 && bmi < 30) {
        answer="Overweight"
    } else {
        answer="Obese"
    }
    return answer
}
```

}
'''

Comment: You should not be accessing views (`findViewById`) or editing them in a ViewModel. The ViewModel should do the relevant calculations, but the actual interface to the views/buttons should be in your activity or fragment. I'd recommend going through a [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-live-data#0) or reading the [LiveData docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) and [ViewModel docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel).

Comment: I think you are getting here a little bit confused. `ViewModel` is used for preserving the data, and it should NOT be responsible for the UI working. For that you have `activity` or `fragment`. So all the business logic(i.e. the calculation should be done in the `ViewModel` while the UI part should be done in the activity or fragment. Hence use the `FindViewById` in a `activity`/`fragment` class.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ViewModel` should contain 2 `MutableLiveData` for `height` and `weight`

You should add 2 `TextWatcher`s to your `EditText`s inside your `Fragment`/`Activity`.

When `afterTextChanged` is called on the `TextWatcher`s, use the `ViewModel`'s `MutableLiveData` to set the value of the corresponding data.

Inside `Fragment`/`Activity`

```
   private val heightTextWatcher = object : TextWatcher {
      override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
          viewModel.height.setValue(s.toString())
      }
      override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
      override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}


   private val weightTextWatcher = object : TextWatcher {
      override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
          viewModel.weight.setValue(s.toString())
      }
      override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
      override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}
```

Inside `ViewModel`

```
public var height: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()
public var weight: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()

fun onCalculate(){
    h = height.getValue()
    w = weight.getValue()
    //do math
}
```

Data never leaves the `ViewModel` and the `View` never the leaves the `Fragment`/`Activity`